# Two way mysql database synchronization

Tags: php, mysql, synchronization, replication

I am developing an application whose database needs to be replicated in both directions over multiple number of local offline clients.

Please see the general explanation about it:

- User installs client software on personal computer.
- User synch data from the remote database server onto local database.
- Now User can work on this local database and perform insert, update, delete on it.
- At the same time other people can also do insert, update, delete on remote database.
- User then connect to remote database and commit their local changes to the remote one.
- User retrieve the remote change(Done by other people in remote database) onto their local database.

Right now the idea in my mind is that, We need to track the changes making in remote and local database and creating the web service for replicating the changes, but somewhere I am getting problem with primary keys that might be the same that generated in local and remote database. But this is approach is very lengthy, I also have doubt that it will work on real time or not.

My question is that is there any technology/tool in the MYSQL Server that help me to achieve this task without creating web services. I read out about mysql replication but it work for only one side replication i.e. Master - Slave, I need two sided synchronization.

Comment: Anybody has a solution for this kind of scenario? I am also looking for solution for similar kind of problem. Please help..

Answer (score 0):

You may use "Replication concept" between Master and Slave database.

You can read and get some idea about it.

http://learnmysql.blogspot.in/2010/10/setup-and-test-mysql-replication-in-20.html

http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/howtos/setting_up_replication.html

Comment: Hi Chinnu R, links your provided works in one sided synchronization(Master to Slave) and I need the solution that works both sided synchronization.

Comment: Devi, useful link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366018/how-to-re-sync-the-mysql-db-if-master-and-slave-have-different-database-incase-o