# Recover master position from database

Tags: mysql, database-replication

i'm trying to configure a master-slave MySQL server.

I'm using this: [How to re-sync the Mysql DB if Master and slave have different database incase of Mysql replication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366018/how-to-re-sync-the-mysql-db-if-master-and-slave-have-different-database-incase-o).
I stopped the master server while i was doing the `mysqldump`, but i lose the `Position` from `SHOW MASTER STATUS;`.

My question is simple, is there any way to know the position of the master in the moment i made the dump?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following [option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_master-data) for mysqldump

```
mysqldump --opt --single-transaction --master-data <DB_NAME>
```

than you can grep dump to find out `change to master` (`head -40 <dumpfile>` will be quite enough)

if you have big databases you should rather go with `innobackupex` Percona utility

Comment: So... i need to do another dump right?, there's no way to know the `Position` value from previous dump