# MySQL Sync with a master database

Tags: mysql, synchronization

I have three MYSQL databases in 3 client applications. I need to sync 3 databases with one master database. I need to make update other databases when master is updated.

Not all the tables few tables from the 3 local databases and there want be integrity errors

[EDIT]

Client databases also sync with master.

Comment: This may also help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366018/how-to-re-sync-the-mysql-db-if-master-and-slave-have-different-database-incase-o

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a custom implementation of distributed database multi-master synching. So I spotted your question immediately.

Please check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html for details on the replication from master to slave.

Hopefully that will give you the most effective info.

Comment: I'm searching for a master master replication solution