# How to re-sync only one slave Mysql DB in case of mysql replication

Tags: mysql, synchronization, replication

I've seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366018/how-to-re-sync-the-mysql-db-if-master-and-slave-have-different-database-incase-o) to re-synchronize a slave database when only one slave is connected to a master DB.

If I understood well, this solution is not the best when we need to resynchronize only 1 slave DB out of batch of slave DBs.

Is there a way to do this, without having to resynchronize all the slave DBs connected to the master ?
I guess the `RESET MASTER` would affect all the slave DBs state and would lead to resynchronize all of them.

Thank you for your help

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution using these mysqldump option to avoid using `RESET MASTER` way :

`mysqldump -p --skip-lock-tables --single-transaction --flush-logs --hex-blob --master-data=2 <dbname>  > /tmp/<dbname>.sql`

This way, the master log bin and position are not changed, but just added on top of the file .sql.

If you set master-data=2 they will be commented in the file

If you set master-data=1 they will not be commented in the file

Once your dump is on your slave host you can reset the slave, import your dump and then run the mysql command `change master to MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysqld-bin.xxxxxxx',MASTER_LOG_POS=xxxx;` with the values indicated in the top of your dump file.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

What in that case with rest of your DBs? If you change binlog and position will they be up to date?

Regards
Robert