# Mysql replication recovery after Slave Reset

Tags: mysql, replication

I had MySQL master slave replication configured. I accidently ran Reset Slave on slave instance. I do not have a note of the last bin log position of the master that the slave had completed. Show slave status command returns a blank row as I have reset the slave. 
Is there any way in which I can recover the last bin log position that the Slave had finished syncing? Or is there any other way in which I can fix the replication without setting it up fresh?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366018/how-to-re-sync-the-mysql-db-if-master-and-slave-have-different-database-incase-o

Comment: It is *possible* that there may be a reference to the last event in the MySQL error log from when you stopped replocation.  If you don't know where this log is, `SELECT @@LOG_ERROR;` to find the path to it.

Comment: Thank you Michael - sqlbot. I could find the last binlog cordinates in the error log