# How to completely disable GTID in mysql 5.7?

Tags: mysql, database-administration, gtid

As my mysql database is just used with a small web app, I won't ever need any replication features. While monitoring, I noticed something named `thread/sql/compress_gtid_table`. And while dumping some tables with `mysqldump` I got this warning:

```
Warning: A partial dump from a server that has GTIDs will by default include the GTIDs of all transactions, even those that changed suppressed parts of the database. If you don't want to restore GTIDs, pass --set-gtid-purged=OFF. To make a complete dump, pass --all-databases --triggers --routines --events.
```

How can I be sure, all GTID features are completely disabled and are not causing overhead ?

Here is my config:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%GTID%';
+----------------------------------+----------------+
| Variable_name                    | Value          |
+----------------------------------+----------------+
| binlog_gtid_simple_recovery      | ON             |
| enforce_gtid_consistency         | OFF            |
| gtid_executed_compression_period | 1000           |
| gtid_mode                        | OFF            |
| gtid_next                        | AUTOMATIC      |
| gtid_owned                       |                |
| gtid_purged                      |                |
| session_track_gtids              | OFF            |
+----------------------------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just linked here while searching for that Warning. I am setting up GTIDs but this page may be helpful for you: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-gtids-howto.html

Note there is a warning that once you turn on GTID you cannot easily go backwards. I'm sure there is a way but it may not be worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

After you disable GTID replication and you don't need more your old binary logs (with GTID info) and slave has catch up all binlog info you can stop slave and do `reset master;` It will wipe out all binlogs from the server and no more gtid information will be kept. Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366018/how-to-re-sync-the-mysql-db-if-master-and-slave-have-different-database-incase-o) how to resync replication properly.