# Can't import the dump: ERROR 1180 (HY000) at line XXXXX1268: Got error 1 "Operation not permitted" during COMMIT

Tags: mariadb, database-replication, database-backups, master-slave

**I am trying to recover my slave cluster. I have followed the guide instructions from here:**
[How to re-sync the Mysql DB if Master and slave have different database incase of Mysql replication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366018/how-to-re-sync-the-mysql-db-if-master-and-slave-have-different-database-incase-o)

The dump from the master has been taken using the following command:

```
mysqldump --all-databases --single-transaction --add-drop-table --master-data=2 --flush-logs > /mnt/sqlbackup/mysqldump.sql
```

I have reset the slave. At the state of importing the dump, I encountered the following error:

```
ERROR 1180 (HY000) at line XXXXX1268: Got error 1 "Operation not permitted" during COMMIT
```

The dump is huge, and I have used the awk command to find what is exactly on that line of the dump. I found the following instruction:

```
--
-- Dumping data for table `d_xxxx_yyy`
--

LOCK TABLES `d_xxxx_yyy` WRITE;
/*!40xxx ALTER TABLE `d_xxxx_yyy` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `d_xxxx_yyy` VALUES
```

The exactly line XXXXX1268 from the error message is `` INSERT INTO `d_xxxx_yyy` VALUES ``

The version of mysql on my server is:

```
Server version: 10.7.3-MariaDB-1:10.7.3+maria~focal-log mariadb.org binary distribution
```

How can I import the dump to restore the Slave?

Comment: What are the values for `autocommit` and `innodb_table_locks` ?

Comment: @GeorgRichter ```autocommit``` is ```ON``` and ```innodb_table_locks``` also is ```ON```

Comment: From MariaDB KB: LOCK TABLES works on XtraDB/InnoDB tables only if the innodb_table_locks system variable is set to 1 (the default) and autocommit is set to 0 (1 is default).

Comment: Thank you, @GeorgRichter So, would the solution be to temporarily set the ```autocommit``` variable to ```0```? Or would it be better not to use the Lock Table variable during the dump creation stage? What would be the safest option without downtime of the master?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, among the SQL generated by mysqldump command, the order of the columns in the INSERT statement was not correct.

I was able to work around it by adding the `mysqldump -c` option to INSERT by column.

Comment: I am curious as to why this flag could help solve the issue. Have you considered why using -c (```Use complete INSERT statements that include column names.```) could resolve the problem?

Comment: Curiously, the order of the values of the insert statements in the generated dump file was disjointed. It took some time to identify the problem, because the error message when restoring showed "Operation not permitted". This is a restore from mysql8ver to mariadb10.11